# Give some idea about the below code? CollectionView inside the Tableview returns same data?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

**Step1:** I created the tableview and custom tableview cell here is the code.**

Structure class:

```
struct DashSection {
var heading : String
var titles : [String]
var images : [String]

init(title : String, subtitle : [String], icons : [String]) {
    heading = title
    titles = subtitle
    images = icons
}
```

}

```
class DashSectionData
{
func getSectionData() -> [DashSection] {
    var arrDash = [DashSection]()
    let firstDic = DashSection(title: "MY ACCOUNT", subtitle: ["Dashboard","Incidents","CAPA","Audits","Reports","Health Register"], icons: ["Heart","DownArrow","DownArrow","DownArrow","DownArrow","DownArrow"])
      let secondDic = DashSection(title: "COMPLIANCE", subtitle: ["Videos","Documents","Training","Safety IQ"], icons: ["DownArrow","DownArrow","DownArrow","DownArrow","DownArrow","DownArrow"])
      let thirdDic = DashSection(title: "RESOURCES", subtitle: ["Videos","Documents","Training","Safety IQ"], icons: ["DownArrow","DownArrow","DownArrow","DownArrow"])
     let fourthDic = DashSection(title: "SETTINGS", subtitle: ["Sites","Users","Forms"], icons: ["DownArrow","DownArrow","DownArrow"])
    arrDash.append(firstDic)
    arrDash.append(secondDic)
    arrDash.append(thirdDic)
    arrDash.append(fourthDic)
    return arrDash
}
```

}

Custom tableview cell with collection view extension:

```
      var dashSection : [DashSection] = DashSectionData().getSectionData()

  class IncidentTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet var viewFull: UIView!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2.0)
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
     // NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.reloadCollectionView), name: .notificationReloadCollection, object: nil)
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
}

extension IncidentTableViewCell : UICollectionViewDataSource
{
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print(section)
    return dashSection[section].titles.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? IncidentProgressCollectionViewCell
    cell?.lblProgress.text = dashSection[indexPath.section].titles[indexPath.row]
    cell?.progressView.value = 0.0
    _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: false, block: { (Timer) in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 6.0) {
            cell?.progressView.value = CGFloat(indexPath.row * 10)
        }
    })
   // callAnimation(cell: cell!, index: indexPath.row, progress: (cell?.progressView)!)
    return cell!
}

func callAnimation(cell: IncidentProgressCollectionViewCell,index:Int,progress: MBCircularProgressBarView)
{
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
        
        cell.progressView.value = CGFloat(index * 10)

        
    }
}

func reloadCollectionView()
{
    if(cellIsSelected.isFirstTime == true)
    {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

}

Tableview datasource and delegate:

```
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
 {
    return dashSection!.count
  }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return dashSection?[section].heading
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? IncidentTableViewCell
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:(cell?.bounds)!,
                            byRoundingCorners:[.bottomRight, .bottomLeft],
                            cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height:  10))
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
    cell?.layer.mask = maskLayer
    return cell!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView()
    let label : UILabel?
    if(section == 0)
    {
        headerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tblView.frame.size.width, height: 60)
        label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 17, y: headerView.center.y - 12.5, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 25))
    }
    else
    {
        headerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tblView.frame.size.width, height: 40)
        label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 17, y: headerView.center.y - 12.5, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 25))
    }
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 250/255, green: 250/255, blue: 250/255, alpha: 1.0)
    
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:headerView.bounds,
                            byRoundingCorners:[.topRight, .topLeft],
                            cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height:  10))
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
    headerView.layer.mask = maskLayer
    //
    //
    
    // let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 17, y: 7, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 25))
    label?.text = dashSection?[section].heading
    label?.textColor = UIColor.orange
    headerView.addSubview(label!)
    return headerView
}
```

Please refer the below attached screen shot. In this screen getting section 0 and return only the section 0th items only. Other items will not be displayed.
i.e I'm getting the section has 0 in collectionview datasource. So Please someone help me to identify the mistake.
TableView shows the correct sections but in collectionView returns first section and the values for the sections only..

Screen shot:
[Returns same data in CollectionView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nizQk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cell?.lblProgress.text = dashSection[TableviewsindexPath.section].titles[CollectionviewsindexPath.row]` should be indexPath.section of tableView not the index path of collectionView

Edit 1

[image]

Comment: func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,    numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print(section)
    return dashSection[section].titles.count
}

Comment: I am not sure Let us test it `cell?.lblProgress.text = dashSection[1].titles[indexPath.row]` replace it with this code and check

Comment: Bro did u try it?

Comment: Yes, I already done this but it getting crash because there is no value of index 1. numberOfItemsInSection returns only the 0. What can i do?

Comment: Can u print your `dashSection` in cellForItemAtIndex path? and send me the results

Comment: Here is the dashSection in cellForAtIndexPath:

Comment: dashSection Results => Dashboard
dashSection Results => Incidents
dashSection Results => CAPA
dashSection Results => Audits
dashSection Results => Reports
dashSection Results => Health Register

Comment: Returns same results for all.

Comment: Bro check your mail and also accept the hangout invite.